# TApplicationEvents with TIdTcpServer Problem?

Tags: delphi, indy, tcpserver

I would like to know if the TApplicationEvents component might cause some problem in case of an exception in the TcpServer OnExecute event, in this case preventing the indy from handling the error correctly.

i mean if use `procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Exception(Sender: TObject; E: Exception);` event

can it generate problems on TIdTcpServer exceptions?

Comment: This question is too broad. You're asking us to speculate on what might happen with some code we cannot see based on something that might happen somewhere at some time. When you have an actual problem and can provide details, you'll have a question that is suitable here. Write a simple test app that uses TApplicationEvents and TIdTCPServer, create an intentional situation that raises an Indy exception, and see what happens. You can also just quickly add the TApplicationEvents to your existing app, add a quick OnException event, and run a quick test - it's easy to remove the OnException event.

Comment: Also, [TApplicationEvents documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Vcl.AppEvnts.TCustomApplicationEvents.OnException) says *Use OnException to change the default behavior that occurs when an exception is not handled by application code.* If Indy is handling the exception, it's not an exception that is *not handled by application code*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TApplication(Events).OnException` event is (normally) triggered only for *unhandled* exceptions that are raised in the context of the main UI thread.  Worker threads do not (usually) trigger the `TApplication(Events).OnException` event. A thread would have to manually call `TApplication.HandleException()` for that to happen. Most threads, including Indy's, do not do that.

`TIdTCPServer` is a multi-threaded component. Its own events, including its `On(Listen)Exception` events, are triggered in the context of internal worker threads, not in the context of the main UI thread.

So, to answer your question, `TApplication(Events)` will not interfere with `TIdTCPServer`'s ability to handle is own exceptions.

Comment: Remy, how i can contact you?

Comment: @PâmellaDouglas there is a contact page on my website, the URL of which is in my StackOverflow profile.